# What is "Pop art blue"?

Tags: meaning, nouns, adjectives

"Across the hills in the pop art blue"

Could I understand "blue" as sadness, depression, like "Across the hills in the sadness of the pop art" or something like that? How can I understand it?

This sentence is a quote from a song named Pop Art Blue from the band Zero 7.

I can't understand the "blue" of this part, which is in the name of the song as well.

The full lyric can be found in here: http://www.songmeanings.net/songs/view/3530822107858799922/

Comment: What I'd like to know is the meaning of "blue" in that sentence...

Answer (score 4):

*Pop Art Blue* appears to be the name given to a specific shade of blue often seen in pop art. Here's [an example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0087S1DNA) of the colour:

[image: Pop art Blue]

It appears to be pretty rare in usage. But there are [34 hits on Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22pop%20art%20blue%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) including this excerpt from one titled *Studies in French Cinema: UK Perspectives, 1985-2010*:

> Ferdinand's death is an absurd irony because at the last minute he cannot put out the touch paper of the dynamite, and his failure transmutes the **pop art blue** painted on his face into the somberly pessimistic shades of de Stael, Yves Klein or ...

Comment: Now I'm wondering if the cosmetic company named their eye shadow shade after the song, or if Zero 7 named their 2009 song after the eye shadow color. At any rate, it looks like "Pop Art blue" is much like "[Windex blue](http://www.google.com/search?q=%2B%22windex+blue%22&hl=en&safe=active&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=UXB0ULqZPLSy0AHk8YDYDw&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=958)" - perhaps just an eyelash more toward teal.

Comment: @J.R. heh. Going by some of the dates on the Google Books results, I think that it's safe to assume that "Zero 7" aren't the source of inspiration for this shade :)